# CSV file with line breaks - load in Athena

Tags: postgresql, csv, hive, relational-database, amazon-athena

I have a CSV file where the CSV cell values contain line breaks.

The CSV file encoding is UTF-8 and I noticed there're also some non-ASCII characters e.g. some Chinese symbols.

What is the easiest way to load this CSV file in an AWS Athena table?

I tried using the standard way (place the file in S3 load using CSV SerDe), but this SerDe doesn't support line breaks.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html

The same data which I have in CSV, I also have it in Postgres.
If loading from there is easier that is also fine. How can it be done?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have the data also in Postgres and I am trying to import it in Athena. If that tag is not right, please remove it.